# Does file_get_contents Downloads the file and saves it to Disk[Harddisk]

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Whenever we use [`file_get_contents` function of PHP](http://php.net/file_get_contents), does the function saves the downloaded page to harddisk? And if yes, where does it save it to?

Also, does it gets auto-delete after the page is closed?

I am using Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; you stand a better chance of getting helpful answers if you put in some effort to solve your own question.

Comment: You mean when you use `file_get_contents` to read from http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_get_contents` reads the entire file into a string, which will be stored in memory (RAM), which will be automatically freed either at the end of the scripts execution or if the variable is unset.

Comment: The only thing i wanted to know :)
Great Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No,it doesn't. It loads it into RAM. You can save it with [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP does not save that file. Actually it's the opposite, it loads it.

So there is nothing to clean up afterwards.

But I wonder a bit why you ask, because I would never have assumed that it saves to disk so you might have some reason to share here additionally.

Comment: Nothing as such, I was just wondering how the code is treated after it fetches the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the source of the page i.e html of the page then you can access it in this way:

`$pageContent = file_get_contents('http://www.anysite.com/anypage.html');`

then in variable $pageContent you will have html of the anypage.html